# Sudo doesn't work: "/etc/sudoers is owned by uid 1005, should be 0" - Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, sudo, sudoers

When I tried to change the user to root using `sudo su` command. it shows the below error. Is there away to solve this issue?

```
dasitha@dev-digin-io:~$ sudo su
sudo: /etc/sudoers is owned by uid 1005, should be 0
sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting
sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin
```

I am using below Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS Server operating system.

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS
Release:        14.04
Codename:       trusty
```

Here's `ls` output:

```
dasitha@dev-digin-io:/etc$ ls -l /etc/sudoers
-r--r----- 1 sajee root 900 Dec 9 07:02 /etc/sudoers
```

This is hosted in google cloud platform (compute Engine / VM ) so I don't have physical access to the machine.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the output of `ls -l /etc/sudoers`. Also please tell us if you would be able to boot the server from alternative media (such as a live CD).

Comment: Did you set up root password? Can you run `su` without `sudo`?

Comment: @MichaelKjörling this is the out put. `dasitha@dev-digin-io:/etc$ ls -l /etc/sudoers
-r--r----- 1 sajee root 900 Dec  9 07:02 /etc/sudoers`

Comment: @techraf no still I got the authentication failure error message.

`dasitha@dev-digin-io:/etc$ su
Password:
su: Authentication failure`

Comment: No @techraf . This is hosted in google cloud platform. (compute Engine / VM )

Comment: @Daz When people request more information, please edit the post to include it. I have made the edit for you; please make them yourself in the future. Thank you.

Comment: When using `su` directly, you need the root password. This is different from `sudo`, where you use your user’s password.

Comment: I have the root password @DanielB. The issue is I can't access the /etc/sudoers. (Explained in the problem)

Comment: If you know the root password, then did you provide it to `su` prompt? And did you get "Authentication failure" in response to the correct (at least in theory) root password?

Comment: Actually, you can access `/etc/sudoers`. It’s just not secure anymore, so `sudo` refuses to use it. `su` does not use `/etc/sudoers`. However, like I mentioned, it requires you to type in the password for root. When exclusively relying on `sudo`, this password may not even be set!

Comment: Thanks for the information @DanielB. What I want to know is. Is there any way to make this thing work ? Or do I need to reinstall the OS ?

Comment: As has been said: Use `su` with the root password to become root, then `chown root /etc/sudoers` to make it secure ("owned by uid 0").

Answer (score 2):

On Google Cloud Platform you can use Startup Scripts to run commands as root on startup. So you can add something similar to `chown 0 /etc/sudoers` to your current script and restart your VM.

And you could read more about Startup Scripts on [Article at Google Cloud Platform](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/startupscript)